# ItemsControl DİsplayMemberPath property does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol

In the following code, the variable named `attributes` is defined as a collection of `SchemaAttribute` objects, in which each object has a "Name" property and bunch of other properties. I create an `ItemsControl` object and bind the attributes to it. I also have an `Expander` object and the data is stored in the expander object.

```cs
Expander expander = new Expander();

var attributes = _dataProvider.GetSchemaAttributes();

ItemsControl itemsControl = new ItemsControl();

itemsControl.ItemsSource = attributes;
itemsControl.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";

expander.Content = itemsControl;
```

Using `DisplayMemberPath` makes expander's content empty. How can I display the Name property properly?

[image: expander]

Comment: Make sure that Name is actually a property, not a field.

Comment: yes you are right. it's field. But why? And is this the only way to solve it?